# Undefined offset: -1", exception in php

Tags: php

I have this array

```
 $arr=   [
      0 => "T"
      1 => "h"
      2 => "e"
      3 => " "
      4 => "w"
      5 => "r"
      6 => "i"
      7 => "t"
      8 => "e"
      9 => "r"
      10 => ""
      11 => " "
      12 => "w"
      13 => "a"
      14 => "s"
      15 => " "
    ..
    ..

for($j=0;$j<count($arr);$j++)
{  
    if($arr[$j-1]==" ")
    {

    }
}
```

In this if condition `if($arr[$j-1]==" ")` getting this error

> message: "Undefined offset: -1", exception: "ErrorException

the previous key exists but i'm still getting error

Any solution to fix this issue

Comment: What happens when j is 0?

Comment: @DanielA.White im getting `if($j==0) { arr[$j] }` output is `T`

Comment: No, you get `if ($arr[-1]) ...`...

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", "Warning: Undefined array key", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-warning-undefined-arr)

Answer (score 1):

```
 $arr=   [
      0 => "T"
      1 => "h"
      2 => "e"
      3 => " "
      4 => "w"
      5 => "r"
      6 => "i"
      7 => "t"
      8 => "e"
      9 => "r"
      10 => ""
      11 => " "
      12 => "w"
      13 => "a"
      14 => "s"
      15 => " "
    ..
    ..

for($j=0;$j<count($arr);$j++)
{  
    if($j > 0 && $arr[$j-1]==" ")
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Index Starts at zero

You are trying to check if the previous key is a space, do something to current key!

`$j` Is starting form zero. so you are checking the index `$j-1`.

To achieve what you want, you should start form `1` to `count($arr)` it self.

Try code below:

```php
for($j = 1; $j < count($arr); $j++)
{  
    if($arr[$j - 1] == " ")
    {
       // do something here
    }
}
```

Or this:

```php
for($j = 0; $j < count($arr) - 1; $j++)
{  
    if($arr[$j] == " ")
    {
       $next = $arr[$j+1];
       // do something here
    }
}
```

Or Even this:

```php
for($j = 0; $j < count($arr); $j++)
{  
    if(isset($arr[$j]) && $arr[$j - 1] == " ")
    {
       // do something here
    }
}
```